# Automatically Capturing a screenshot of the page after login without use of webdrivers ., via scheduler using springboot java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've implemented a scheduler for logging into a website making sure that the server is up. Here Additionally I want to capture a screenshot automatically when logged in without using any web drivers . Because the version of the chrome driver and my chrome browser version is a mismatch.
Thereby i want to implement this programatically in java without using web drivers .

I've tried implementing it using web drivers as the version gets mismatched i cannot proceed further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.